# What are the little green men in The Secret World of Og?

Tags: childrens-novel

In [The Secret World of Og](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_World_of_Og) by Pierre Burton, a world populated by little green men that only say "Og" is found by Penny, Pamela, Peter, Patsy, and baby Paul (AKA “The Pollywog") through a hole in the floor of their clubhouse.

**Did the author ever explain what he thought these little green men were?
Are they frog men? salamanders? elves? martians?! or something else entirely?**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I believe they are not frog men or salamanders. They have ears in the illustration which a frog man or salamander would not have. They are a mix between elves and goblins. A martian from Mars would most likely be on Mars. What would the motivation of them to come to earth is.

Comment: So you're saying... You have no idea. This is an opinion rather than an answer, and not what we are looking for on this site.